# Row content with a string of key-values to match corresponding columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, data-manipulation

**Requirement**
Expand one column where a string of key-values with variable length is stored to multiple columns with corresponding values by Spark using the API of Scala from a source of parquet.

**Example**
Input

```
+----------+-------------------------------------+
| identity | Original                            |
+----------+-------------------------------------+
| 1        | key1=value1&key2=value2             |
+----------+-------------------------------------+
| 2        | key2=value2&key3=value3&key7=value7 |
+----------+-------------------------------------+
```

Output

```
+----------+-------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| identity | Original                            | key1   | key2   | key3   | key7   |
+----------+-------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 1        | key1=value1&key2=value2             | value1 | value2 |        |        |
+----------+-------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2        | key2=value2&key3=value3&key7=value7 |        | value2 | value3 | value7 |
+----------+-------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

**My progress**
By reading over multiple articles here, I've got to the final step. The following is my effort to fulfil the requirement:

1. Get the aggregation of keys from `Original`

   ```
   val base = spark.read.parquet("path.of.parquet")
   val aggregationKeys = base.select($"Original").rdd.map{
     case observation => {
       val immediate = observation.toString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split("&")
       immediate.map(_.split("=")(0))
     }
   }.collect.flatMap(y=>y).sorted.distinct
   ```
2. Create new columns based on the keys

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.types._  
   import org.apacje.spark.sql.Row  
   val aggregationKeysString = aggregationKeys.mkString("、")  
   val keysFields = aggregationKeysString.split("、")  
     .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable=true)) 

   val keysSchema=StructType(keysFields)  
   val keysColumns = spark.createDataFrame(  
     spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row], keysSchema  
     ).withColumn("identity", lit(0))  
   val transformedBase = base.join(keysColumns, Seq("identity"), "left_outer")
   ```
3. [Struggling] Some Scala code that is logically equivalent to *if a key exists in `Original`, its value becomes the content of the corresponding column out from Step 2 as the output of Example displays*. My thought is getting a collection of key-value pairs on each row of `Original`, then conveying the values to their corresponding column

How to achieve the goal of Step 3? Considering performance, is there a better solution to achieve the requirement? Because the number of keys may be up to hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

The question I've been stuck on was solved by [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39978880/transforming-one-column-into-multiple-ones-in-a-spark-dataframe?rq=1) found on this site after I posted.

## Solution

```
val base = spark.read.parquet("path.of.parquet")

//Get the whole keys in the form of array
val aggregationKeys = base.select($"Original").rdd.map{
  case observation => {
    val immediate = observation.toString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split("&")
    immediate.map(_.split("=")(0))
  }
}.collect.flatMap(y=>y).sorted.distinct

//Turn the collection of array to the collection of map
val columnNames: Seq[String] = aggregationKeys.filter(_.nonEmpty).toSeq
val mapifyValue = udf[Map[String, String], String] {
    s => s.split("&").map(_.split("=")).map{
        case Array(k, v) => k -> v
    }.toMap
}

//Get the result as the output of Example portrays
val stringAsMap = tmp.withColumn("mapifiedOriginal", mapifyValue($"Original"))
val ultimateResult: DataFrame = columnNames.foldLeft(stringAsMap) {
    case (df, colName) => 
            df.withColumn(colName, $"mapifiedOriginal".getItem(colName))
}.drop("mapifiedOriginal")
```

C'est la vie.

Comment: Interesting. Between two sentences with the same meaning, French version was kept while traditional Chinese was moved. BTW, a phrase from The Lion King was deleted, too.

Comment: **I won't edit again since the core part stands there**. Either every part on this site should be neutral as much as possible or editing with bias to some extent by people couldn't be stove off.
 
[Why is “fulfil” spelt as “fulfill” in American English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76057/why-is-fulfil-spelt-as-fulfill-in-american-english)